# How to center top Menu bar

Tags: menus

On the top is a grey bar containing different pages. However, it is not centered and appears left justified.

Anyone know how to fix this? I am using the Vortex theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add this rule to your CSS somewhere.

This positions the menu list 50% from the left, then translate the X 50% in the opposite direction.

```
.menu > ul.sf-js-enabled {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

More info

- http://caniuse.com/#search=transform
- http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/translatex/
- http://howtocenterincss.com/